# VSTS code coverage for Scala

Tags: scala, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, scoverage

My team is using Microsoft VSTS as SLM tool. We are using Scala for our backend services and code coverage tool is scoverage. Is there a way I can see code coverage for scala services in VSTS? As of now I see only Cobertura and Jacoco supported for CC in VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VSTS build, the code coverage only support Cobertura and JaCoCo formats.

Mode details, you can refer the task [Publish Code Coverage Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=vsts).

So you need to convert the fomat to Cobertura or JaCoCo. Such as use the plugin [sbt-jacoco](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jacoco).